# solution for first order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given ODE $f'+(ax+b)f=\frac{1}{x}$. There are different approaches to solve this equation when we have a polynomial in $x$ on the righthand side. What is a way to solve with $\frac{1}{x}$
on the RHS? Or how to find a particular solution for this equation (because homogeneous one is easy to find) ?

With integrating factor, if I understand right, I have
$P(x)=ax+b$, $Q(x)=\frac{1}{x}$
The integrating factor $e^{-\int P(x)dx}=e^{-\frac{(ax+b)^2}{2a}}$, which leads to
$f=e^{-\frac{(ax+b)^2}{2a}}\left[\int e^{\frac{(ax+b)^2}{2a}}\frac{1}{x}dx+C\right]$. What am I doing next with this integral? How can I evaluate it explicitly?

Comment: I don't think you can evaluate that integral with elementary functions. You have to leave it that way.

Comment: The result can be stated in terms of the [exponential integral](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialIntegral.html) $\operatorname{Ei}$.